# How to restart the message consumer in Spring Integration?

Tags: spring, asynchronous, activemq-classic, messaging, spring-integration

My consumer, e.g. service activator that is consuming messages coming from ActiveMQ fromChannel should be restarted when exception occurs or ActiveMQ fails. How to do it for the following spring integration context ?

```
 <!-- RECEIVER. message driven adapter -> jmsInChannel -> activator. -->

<si:channel id="fromChannel"/>

<int-jms:message-driven-channel-adapter id="messageDrivenAdapter"
    channel="fromChannel" destination="forward" connection-factory="connectionFactory"
    max-concurrent-consumers="2" auto-startup="true" acknowledge="auto" extract-payload="false" />

<si:service-activator id ="activator" 
    input-channel="fromChannel"
    ref="messageService" 
    method="process"/>

<bean id="messageService" class="com.ucware.ucpo.forward.jms.MessageService"/>
```

My first idea was to use [Retry Advice](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/htmlsingle/#retry-advice) and add  to a service  but am not sure if this a right solution for unhandled exceptions. I also would like the receiver to restart if the ActiveMQ server is down.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The listener container within the `message-driven-channel-adapter` will automatically keep trying to reconnect when it loses connectivity to the broker.

If you set `acknowledge="transacted"' the message will be rolled back on an exception and the broker will resubmit it.

A stateful retry advice would allow you to give up and take some other action after some number of retries (but you can also configure that into ActiveMQ itself where it will send the message to a DLQ after some number of delivery attempts).

Comment: SI is really great :) Would that also work for the sender, for example outbound-channel-adapter and gateway?

Comment: Will the attempt to reconnect with the broker last forever? This is a functionality I need.

Comment: For the outbound adapter you'd need to retry after a failure. Yes, the message-driven adapter will keep retrying to connect  "for ever".

Comment: Could you provide some hints how to configure the retry for outbound adapter?

Comment: Documentation: http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#message-handler-advice-chain        Sample: https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-integration-samples/tree/master/intermediate/retry-and-more

Answer (score 1):

Reading your post I instantly thought of [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TetfR7ULnA8). Which gives a good insight on how to monitor and control SI application through itself.

Additionally you should have a look at [ApplicationEvent](http://static.springsource.org/spring-integration/reference/html/applicationevent.html) documentation of SI.

Glueing that all together you could monitor the JMS message adapter with JMX and stop and restart it through sending an ApplicationEvent on issues. Regarding catching exceptions it depends on what Exceptions you actually want to handle. I'd create an errorChannel that receives exceptions being thrown by components and create a new service that restarts these components after receiving errors.

Following your idea leveraging [Spring Retry](http://blog.springsource.org/2012/10/09/spring-integration-2-2-retry-and-more/)'s capabilites in SI.